# How to configure default phone call app on Mac

Tags: macos, iphone, call, continuity

Skype for Business has been my Mac's default phone call app ever since I installed it. Is there a way to switch to FaceTime—or better yet, handoff to iPhone?

When I place calls from my iPhone, I can switch the audio to my Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Open FaceTime on your Mac, select FaceTime > Preferences, select Settings, then change Default for calls to FaceTime.

via https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7715107

[image]

Comment: seems like it belongs in System Preferences

Comment: I don't have this setting in my facetime preferences, does someone know how to make it appear?

Comment: The weirdest thing about this is that it doesn't just change the defaults for the `Contacts.app`'s "FaceTime Audio" option, but for the "Call Using iPhone" one as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you're not logged into the FaceTime app with an Apple ID, the **FaceTime | Settings...** menu option is grayed out. Logging into FaceTime with an Apple ID made the menu option available, allowing me to change these settings.